# Allow customer to edit angular / express / mongo - MEAN stack content

Tags: angularjs, mongodb, express, content-management-system, mean-stack

I've recently switched from developing wordpress sites to learning angular, express, mongo, passport etc etc. Wordpress obviously provides a (relatively) simple interface whereby the user can manage their own page content.

My question is, is there a standard procedure for achieving this using the above technologies? I'm currently building my first site proper using MEAN for a friend and I want to give her the means to go in and update images, text, add pages, remove pages etc etc but via a user friendly interface.

I've a feeling I'm going to have to build it myself but before I launch into doing that I was wondering if there was anything glaringly obvious that I'm missing?

Thanks in advance

Comment: If you're goal is ultimately something equivalent to Wordpress I'd say follow the golden rule: don't roll your own.  What I'm getting at here: its probably best to just continue using Wordpress.  They have already a feature-rich, proven product that is much more complex to implement than you might realize.  They've (hopefully) done their due diligence with regards to security and quality assurance leveraging an entire team rather than a single developer.  I know this may not be the answer you're looking for.  It will be much more of a learning experience than a quick favor for a friend.

Comment: Thanks for that - to be honest, the decision to go with Angular / MEAN is more of a career oriented one - I've spent a fair while working with WordPress (and believe me, I know how complicated to implement it can be) but now wish to work with Angular. What I really want to know is what the standard approach is or even if there is one when building MEAN websites for clients and then handing them over? I was kind of hoping there's be some nice out of the box solution but I don't think that's going to be the case.